# How to get a job in the game industry if you live in a country where there are no game companies?

Tags: game-industry, career, hiring

You know not everyone of us is living in the US/Europe where there is potentially many more employers/opportunities than other countries, I live in a country where there is literally zero game companies (aside from a couple of companies that make HTML games), but I am sure there are many other people with the same situation, I am making some prototype games that will/might help.

But the real question is there any better way to get noticed (at least get an interview) by international companies, or given you are living far away will diminish their interest in hiring you?

-This question might be considered subjective or even a duplicate, but I feel am addressing an issue that might not have been addressed.

Comment: by applying to jobs. I´m from Sweden but work in Finland. I have went to interviews in England and Germany.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote.. the question clearly asks for people who are NOT living in Europe/US. By applying for jobs isn't really an answer since you are living outside you will throw your CV with thousands of other people and you won't get your chance..

Comment: What i mean is, that there is no difference in being from another company. the gaming industry is so small compared to other industry that you get hired from where ever you are living. And the only way is to apply for jobs.

Comment: @Tordin The game industry is the biggest industry in the world -_-. It caught up to the film industry over a year ago.....

Comment: Money based maybe, but thats not what i meant, i meant how many there is actually working in the industry. And an offtopic road, no i barley think that the game industry is making more money than Electronic industry, oil industry or car industry or even war industry.

Comment: @Tordin Facts please. This is something one should not have opinion based opinions. I really could not say gaming industry a small industry. It may be a small export industry in Sweden or Finland, but it still is the largest import of all entertainment industries. There is a lot of money in there, and that's why gaming indusry is growing in Sweden and Finland as we speak.

Comment: Okay, Again let me reform the question here. I am generally speaking about how many people there is in the industry, NOT how much money they are making. Basicly EVERY Company there (not counting those with under 20 employees ) is searching for people because there is just not enough talent.

Comment: The answer is the same for getting a job in any industry. You either apply and hope, have good connections, or you have impressive skills. I'd say this question is too opinion based or too broad, since that's inevitably the way these types of questions go. There's no single correct answer to "How to get a job" in any field, regardless of the circumstances.

Comment: Depending on your age, you may first want to go to the desired country as a student, and apply from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is this:

1) Have skills that the industry needs.

2) Have a strong portfolio that you can show off demonstrating the skills from #1.

3) Make contacts in the industry.  This means being active on social media networks that folks in the industry care about.

4) Collaborate on small projects with others to prove that you can work independently, with others, and still get things done.

Comment: +1 for make contacts in the industry. I think this the most important to get noticed, you may have the skills still if you don't know anyone nobody will notice you.

Comment: Basically the same way you'd get a job in any industry, regardless if there's a presence in your country.

Comment: (was waiting for someone to point that out... glad I could count on you, @Byte56)

Answer (score -1):

This is my experience and opinions, and some people might disagree with me. Do not read this as hard facts, but more or less as a guide. I also know this is not exactly the answer for what you asked in your question. Instead it is one of the many answers for the question "how to get employed in the gaming industry" in the title.

Why don't you start your own business? Running a business is fairly easy, at least it is here in Finland. The business part is easy enough in the beginning, and when the company gets bigger you can always hire help to do the business stuff for you if you prefer to just create the games. The only real challenge is to get the customers, but that's so easy on gaming industry nowdays when compared to other software industries, or any other industry. Why do I say that? Well.. There's so much publishing platforms nowdays. [Steam Greenlight](http://steamcommunity.com/greenlight), [gog.com](http://www.gog.com/indie), [indie royale](http://www.indieroyale.com/faq) and [Totalbiscuit](http://www.youtube.com/user/TotalHalibut) to say at least, and most likely a lot more stuff I do not know about.

You said you are making some prototypes. That's really all these publishing platforms need. Just try to get a green light for your game prototype in steam, and after that you are much better off to take the risk and get a loan from bank to hire some help with the areas of expertise you might not be good at, like graphics or sounds or programming. You also might try out some of these cheap contract-based work websites like [fiverr](http://fiverr.com/).

I am not saying it won't be hard road to travel. But if you succeed, you will be more than satisfied.

Comment: 1. when the asker says that there are no game companies in his country, this might have a reason. Maybe where he lives is a bad location for such a business 2. starting your own game development company requires money, because it takes years until you will get the first revenue. Crowdfunding rarely helps, because it is unlikely to be successful when you haven't already done considerable work.

Comment: @Philipp As I said, I represented it just as an option for anyone having a similar question. It wasn't an answer spesificly for this question.

Comment: @Lasse Answers should be specific to the question being asked. This isn't a discussion forum.

Comment: @Byte56 I disagree. Stack Exchange style sites are especially designed to provide answers to people with similar questions that search for answers. While for the reason you mentioned an up-vote might not be appropriate, I don't think a down-vote is either. I found this answer informative and helpful (even if it was not 100% applicable to this person).

Comment: @MrUniverse That sounds like a very slippery slope. If someone were asking an XNA question, I wouldn't suggest they switch to Unity because that thing they want to do is easier in Unity. Asking how to get a job and being answered with "start a company" is similarly not reasonable.

Comment: @Byte56 For me "start a company" was exactly the answer for question "how to get employed in gaming industry".

Comment: @Byte56 I edited the answer a bit. Is it now more on topic?